# How to show the limit by definition

Tags: calculus

How to go about the proof of the limit of $\ln(x+y)$ being equal to $\ln(4\pi/3)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(\pi,\pi/3)$.

Comment: What does $\ln$ mean to you?

Comment: An abbreviation for natural logarithm

Comment: Yes, and how have you defined the natural logarithm?

Answer (score 0):

As $(x,y) \rightarrow (\pi\frac{\pi}{3})$, $x+y\rightarrow \frac{4\pi}{3}$.
Now use the fact that $\ln$ is continuous. And
$\lim_{a \to \frac{4\pi}{3}}\ln(a)=\ln (\frac{4\pi}{3})$.

Comment: I can't figure out what to do here